# admin Panel: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting this error while trying to upload a picture in http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
[23/Oct/2020 12:15:22] "POST /admin/store/category/4/change/ HTTP/1.1" 500 166634

I'm using MacOS 10.15.7
Python 3.9
Django 3.1.2
pandas 1.1.3

```
from django.db import models

    class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product', blank=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add view and settings file? and the html code you added the image to

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `upload_to='product'` it requires MEDIA_ROOT. Try the following:

1. Add two folders in your project directory called `'media'` and `'media/product'`
2. In `settings.py` add the code below at the bottom

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

[Django 'Model Field Reference docs'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/)

Comment: I have added such lines in my settings as follow: 
'STATIC_URL = '/static/' '
'STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles',)'
'STATICFILES = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]'
'MEDIA_URL = '/media/' '
'MEDIA_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')]'